# Creating an account for cpanel

Tags: installation, ssh, cpanel

I've successfully installed CPanel on my CentOS VPS via SSH. Now I can see

> https://~my website ip~:2087/

It prompts me a username and password with the title: `Web Host Manager` now I have no idea what the default username and password is... I did not set up any accounts, I just installed the CPanel and left it to be installed and I certainly have not seen any kind of username and password set up.

How will I be able to set up a username and password for my CPanel so I can log in to it.

The CPanel came from this website: `http://layer1.cpanel.net/latest`.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, please repeat? Username is `root` and password is `rootpassword`? Well neither of all of them works.

Comment: Use as USERNAME: "root" and use YOUR ROOTPASSWORD as a PASSWORD, or try using YOUR USERNAME as a USERNAME and your USERPASSWORD as a PASSWORD, i don't know that program in specific but most control panel programs use that as default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use as USERNAME: "root" and use YOUR ROOTPASSWORD as a PASSWORD, or try using YOUR USERNAME as a USERNAME and your USERPASSWORD as a PASSWORD, i don't know that program in specific but most control panel programs use that as default